# input css expand issue when clicking submit button

Tags: html, css, button, input, focus

so when i click on the input field.. it expands which is awesome. but when i click onto the submit button. it shrinks.. how do i keep it expanded?

HTML:

```
<div class="search-container">
  <input class="from-control" id="searchTerm" name="textarea"
  type="search" placeholder="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button" name="button"
   id="search">Search</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-container {
margin-top: 25px;
}

.from-control {
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 4px;
width: 124px;
height: 35px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
}

input.from-control:focus {
width: 40vmax;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `:focus` to expand the input it logically shrinks when the focus is changed to something else (in this case the submit button). I guess that you do an asynchronous call when clicking the submit button, since you have no action in the form.

A possible solution is to create a new class

```
input.form-control.expanded {
    width: 40vmax;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Then in your `onClick()` function you can add the class to the input field using `addCLass("expanded")`.

Comment: thank you! you were on the right track. i used jquery simply add $('input').focus(); into my $('#search').click function. :)